# How to push a new controller from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, rubymotion

I've got two classes. One is for `ItemController` (extends `UITableViewController`) and another is `ItemCell` (extends 'UITableViewCell').

When each cell is clicked I push a new controller from within `ItemController`'s `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Additionally, in `ItemCell`, I've got couple of small buttons with different `tag` for each cell. When any of these buttons are clicked I want to push a new controller. How can I do this?

`self.navigationController.pushViewController` from `ItemCell` doesn't work since it doesn't have `navigationController`

I would prefer to see a solution in RubyMotion but if not, thats fine too :)

**Edit**

I've read that `delegate` can be a solution but I'm not sure how to implement it. This is what I've done

ItemController:

```
  def tableView(table_view, cellForRowAtIndexPath: index_path)
    data_row = self.data[index_path.row]
    cell = table_view.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CATEGORY_CELL_ID) || begin
      rmq.create(ItemCell.initWithSomething(self), :category_cell, reuse_identifier: CATEGORY_CELL_ID).get
    end
    cell.update(data_row)
    cell
  end
```

ItemCell:

```
class ItemCell < UITableViewCell

  attr_accessor :delegate
  def initWithSomething(delegate)
    @delegate = delegate
  end

  ...use @delegate to push the new controller
end
```

but I get an error

> item_controller.rb:114:in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:':
>   undefined method`initWithSomething' for ItemCell:Class
>   (NoMethodError)

Comment: Have you tried something before asking?

Comment: You can't "push" a new view controller without a navigation controller. You can present (modally) one by using presentViewController:animated:completion:

Comment: @oski555 I've updated the question with approach I've unsuccessfully tried

Comment: @rdelmar I do have navigation in the `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is that you cell should tell your view controller that something happened and than is the View Controller that will decided to push the other View Controller.

You can do that with the delegate design pattern:

`ItemCell` has a `delegate` property that conform to a protocol. For example

```
@class ItemCell
@protocol ItemCellDelegate
- (void)itemCellDidClickSubmitButton:(ItemCell *)cell;
@end

@interface ItemCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ItemCellDelegate> delegate
...
@end
```

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you will set the controller as the cell delegate (obviously the view controller should conform to the `ItemCellDelegate`):

```
cell.delegate = self
```

The button on your cell will trigger an IBAction on the cell itself that in turn will call the delegate method

```
- (IBAction)submitButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    id <ItemCellDelegate> delegate = self.delegate;
    if ([delegate respondToSelector:@selector(itemCellDidClickSubmitButton:)]) {
        [delegate itemCellDidClickSubmitButton:self];
    } 
}
```

And obviously in your View Controller you should do something like:

```
#pragma mark - ItemCellDelegate

- (void)itemCellDidClickSubmitButton:(ItemCell)cell
{
    UIViewController *controller = // Create the view controller to push
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller];
}
```